# Listings: Inline text too small in headlines

Tags: listings

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{General} {
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily
}

\lstset{style=General}

\begin{document}

\chapter{MyChapter with some \lstinline|inline text|}
Here is some text with some \lstinline|inline text|

\end{document}
```

I am using the `\lstinline` very often in my texts. The font size should be `\small` within these texts. But sometimes I have to use the \lstinline in my chapter headlines. Of course now there are small too which looks weird. How can I change the fontsize only for these chapter headers?

Comment: Why don't you use simply \texttt{inline text} in the header? verbatim commands like \lstinline doesn't work well in the arguments of other commands anyway.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer great idea. But now it looks too heavy. Is there a way to make it one size smaller than the other text (that's the reason why I make inline text size=small at default: For me one size below the rest looks much better...)

Comment: in your example it doesn't look to heavy. Are you using other fonts in your real document? Then you should better ask a new question how to scale down the tt-font so that it matches.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see, it's the inconsolata package I included which makes it look heavy. The question now is: Can I disable the inconsolata at headlines for texttt?

Comment: That's a new question, so ask a new question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476162/disable-inconsolata-package-in-headlines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\lstinline` has an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{General} {
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily
}

\lstset{style=General}

\begin{document}

\chapter{MyChapter with some \lstinline[basicstyle=\Huge\ttfamily]|inline text|}
Here is some text with some \lstinline|inline text|

\end{document}
```

[image]

According to the documentation:

> `\lstinline` has an optional argument? Yes. And from this fact comes a
>   limitation: you can’t use the left bracket `[` as delimiter unless you
>   specify at least an empty optional argument as in `\lstinline[][var i:integer;[`.
>   If you forget this, you will either get a “runaway
>   argument” error from TeX, or an error message from the keyval package.

Comment: In this example it works. But for some reason in my whole document at one point the compiler calls "basicstyle undefined in families lst". It works for a certain chapter size but at one point this error appears. I think I could go with the solution of @UlrikeFischer. Thanks nevertheless