# Disable inconsolata package in headlines

Tags: inconsolata

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{General} {
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily
}

\lstset{style=General}

\begin{document}

\chapter{MyChapter with some \texttt{inline text}}
Text with \lstinline|inline text|

\end{document}
```

I am using the `inconsolata` font for inline texts and listings. With `\texttt` I am using inline texts in chapter headlines too (Because [using `\lstinline` inside cheapter headlines result in an error on my document, `\texttt` not](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476124/listings-inline-text-too-small-in-headlines)). Although the font looks great, the normal font size looks too heavy for me. That's why I am decreasing the font size of listings to `\small`.

Is there a way to decrease the font size for the `\texttt` within chapters too or disable the `inconsolata` package in chapter headlines (Without it looks ok for me)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inconsolata knows a scale factor that you can use to adjust the font size.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.94]{inconsolata} %or some other value

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{General} {
    basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\lstset{style=General}

\begin{document}

\chapter{MyChapter with some \texttt{inline text} \textmd{\texttt{inline text}}}
Text with \texttt{inline text} \lstinline|inline text|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It undo the bold.